# Parse Notifications Not Sending (iOS)

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I am not able to see the error that I am getting, but it shows it under "Other" that the push notification was unsuccessful. Where can I find out more details of this error?

Comment: could you be more specific and maybe add a picture of your problem? is the error on Parse? on your app when a notification is sent?